# UWP Restricted Capability not working for broadFileSystemAccess

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to access some files and directories using a UWP app that a local user should have access to for my specific scenario. It wasn't working, so I tested the API on just the general user-level directory and sub-directories to the same effect of `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities

1. Add `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"` to the `Package`
2. Add `rescap` to ignorable namespaces (I also tried w/out this btw)
3. Added `<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />` to the `Capabilities` section

Here's a link to the gist for the manifest. It was just a new default Universal app created in VS2017: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/01621d68b7b6a92067780dc69cdf9ded

Here's a link to the gist for the CSProj: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/c95db9fc89e71f38969da9af6203d3a8

The mainpage in the sample project is just one new method and a call to it:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    GetUserFolder();
}

public async void GetUserFolder()
{
    var get = 
      await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\user name");
}
```

So for example, this wouldn't work either:

```cs
var get = 
await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\user name\\New Folder");
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue. If I add the capability the code works as expected. Did you check the minimum/target version for your project? It might be the cause if those versions are too low.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I've updated it to share the project file too. I should be able to use it with the targeted versions as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you developing a desktop bridge project or a UWP project?

Comment: Open the 'Settings' app and go to Privacy->File System. Make sure file access for your app is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Stefan Wick MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686985/stefan-wick-msft) for providing guidance.

For me, the issue wasn't actually in the code. It had to do how the Restricted Capability works with operating system permissions. There might be a way to help automate this step with PowerShell but I'm not aware of it.

Unlike including another [Restricted Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) such as `App Close Confirmation` with `<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />` by adding it to the package manifest, you have to ***also*** make adjustments to the actual operating system settings for it to take effect. I'm sure this is documented somewhere but it's not exactly prominently warning you about it at the moment let alone telling you how to fix it. Specifically it warns,

> Because users can grant or deny the permission any time in **Settings**, you should ensure that your app is resilient to those changes. In the April 2018 update, the default for the permission is On. In the **October 2018 update**, the **default is Off**.

To facilitate those changes,

Enable `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `File system` -> `Allow apps to access your file system`

Then find your app after you've installed it, and select the checkbox to allow file system access via `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `File system` -> `Choose which apps can access your file system` as shown below.

[image]